# SD disk with win 10 is corrupted - how to fix it?

Tags: gparted, disk, sd-card, data-corruption

I'm currently using Ubuntu but would like to also install win 10 - But I cannot do anything with my SD disk

Any ideas how to fix it? <- I dont care about data at /dev/sdb, just wanna make it work (Having bootable win + new activation keys)

```
owozniak@owozniak-GL702ZC:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -O 64bit /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sdb1 contains a vfat file system labelled 'SYSTEM'

Warning: could not erase sector 2: Input/output error
Creating filesystem with 266240 1k blocks and 66792 inodes
Filesystem UUID: a1136bd1-de07-4fc9-9113-035e93d4c8c9
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729, 204801, 221185

Allocating group tables: done                            
Warning: could not read block 0: Input/output error
Warning: could not erase sector 0: Input/output error
Writing inode tables: done                            
ext2fs_update_bb_inode: Input/output error while setting bad block inode


owozniak@owozniak-GL702ZC:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Your SD Card is not corrupted - it's *faulty*. Time to replace it.

Comment: @user535733 - How you know that? And as I understand I need to disable it in bios because installing win10 process is freezing?

Comment: The multiple input/output errors are the key indicator. That is NOT usual behavior. You normally see multiple I/O errors in dying (faulty) storage devices.